# Search in xml nodes using web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML file with node!
im trying to create web servic search ! without using database, use the same xml file .
any possible example ?

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> find(string id)
{

    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("books.xml");

    string test = null;
    IEnumerable<XElement> listOfBooks = xelement.Elements();

    List<string> attributes = new List<string>();
    foreach (var _books in listOfBooks)
    {
        if(_books.Element("title").Value==id )
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_books.Element("genre").Value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_books.Element("title").Value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_books.Element("description").Value);
            attributes.Add(_books.Element("genre").Value);
            attributes.Add(_books.Element("title").Value);
            attributes.Add(_books.Element("description").Value);
            test = _books.Element("description").Value;

        }

    }
    return attributes;

}
```

I want to divide the returned list.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information. When you have some code to show people here can most likely help you :)

Comment: trying to find all XML sibling nodes as web service that i can call it

Comment: Your passing an ID to the function, and you want to return a list of strings. Am I correct in understanding you wish to return all books whose title matches the `id` passed to the method? And what do you mean by "divide the returned list"?